# In the context of Windows, are the terms Daemon and Service interchangable?

Tags: windows, unix, service, daemon

It is my understanding that Daemon is a popular term in the Unix world to refer to a process that runs without a terminal or human interaction. It runs continuously until it has completed its task. It may complete a task, wait for a bit, and then repeat the process.

In the Windows world, I typically hear people talk about Services. A Service seems to fit the description of a Daemon.

Are they just two terms for the same thing?

Comment: @HarryJohnston I didn't think Windows used the term "daemon" myself, but I have been hearing it a lot in my office. We actually have some Windows Services with Daemon in the name. That was very confusing to me, so I figured I would get some clarification. So do all Services in Windows depend on the Service Manager? As for the exe's named like Daemons, let me check on that. I could be wrong.

Comment: `in Windows there are exe's named as Daemons (as in the end in a D)` As noted already, some examples would help. FWIW another convention in Windows has an ending `D` stand for debug builds (not _daemon_) e.g. Microsoft's own `msvcrt` vs. `msvcrtD`. You are not supposed to encounter debug builds on a production machine, though.

Comment: @HarryJohnston Updated to remove that comment. I misread another post that listed some Daemons and thought they were referring to Windows. I believe you have answered my question but cant mark your comments as the correct answer. If you can provide an answer I would like to give you credit for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't uncommon for developers with a UNIX background to write Windows applications (usually ports) that use UNIX terminology.  However, Windows itself does not use the term "daemon" and it is not in mainstream use amongst the Windows community.

Daemon *can* be (and in the past has been) legitimately used as a generic computing term with a fairly broad meaning, but nowadays it is normally used only to refer specifically to UNIX or UNIX-like daemons.  Any other use risks confusion.

Windows services (specifically, Windows Service Applications) are not in my opinion similar enough to UNIX daemons to be sensibly described in that way.  In particular, they are started and stopped only via the Service Control Manager and have to interface with the SCM in a specific way.

(On the other hand, from what I've read about systemd services, they *do* appear to be conceptually similar to Windows Service Applications.  I don't know whether they are commonly referred to as daemons in the UNIX community.)